# Dataframe Schema prints out empty

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm trying out the Scala Spark creating dataframes.
But this returns an empty DF Schema and empty DF.

Can someone tell me what is the issue here? Thanks!

````
           val simpleData = Seq(Row("James","","Smith","36636"),
              Row("Michael","Rose","","40288"),
              Row("Robert","","Williams","42114"),
              Row("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192"),
              Row("Jen","Mary","Brown","")
            )

            val simpleSchema = StructType(Array(
              StructField("firstname",StringType,true),
              StructField("middlename",StringType,true),
              StructField("lastname",StringType,true),
              StructField("id", StringType, true)
            ))

            val df = spark.createDataFrame(
              sc.parallelize(simpleData),simpleSchema)
            logger.info(s"df printschema: ${df.printSchema()}")
            logger.info(s"df show: ${df.show}")
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.printSchema()` will print the schema of the dataframe to output and not return a value that would be printed by your logger. You may access the schema as a [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) using `df.schema`.

Try changing

```scala
logger.info(s"df printschema: ${df.printSchema()}")
```

to

```scala
logger.info(s"df printschema: ${df.schema.simpleString}")
```

or

```scala
logger.info(s"df printschema: ${df.schema.json}")
```

for the json representation.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Just one more question, why is it that df.show() doesn't print anything as well? 
How will I be able to print the content of my df?

Comment: Having `df.show()` on a line by itself should print the output on the main driver node by default. If you would like to stream/print results using your logger, you may have to use `logger.info(s"df show: ${df.collect()}")` or rather `logger.info(s"df show: ${df.take(20)}")` since you may overload your driver node if you try to retrieve all the results distributed amongst other nodes of the cluster.